# String slicing, iterations and list question

Tags: python, string

Say I have the string "BigJon".

Is there way to iterate through and slice it into two different words like 
`B igJon`, `Bi gJon`, `Big Jo`n, `Bigj on` and so on. And then all these separate pieces be a list?

Comment: Or in Python 3.6: `[f'{a[:i]} {a[i:]}' for i in range(1, len(a))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner list comprehension

`['%s %s' % (a[:i], a[i:]) for i in range(1, len(a))]`

Comment: All of that makes sense except for the '%%', %. Care to explain?

Comment: @KelvinDavis Its called [string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Comment: its a standard print format specifier. `%s` is used for a string, `%d` for an integer etc. in this case, I want to print two strings separated by a space. Hence `%s %s`.  Yes, as @leaf says, its string interpolation.

Comment: @KelvinDavis aka [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) which Python "inherited" from C.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'Bigjohn'
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    b = s[:i]+" "+s[i:]
    print b
```

output:

```
 Bigjohn
B igjohn
Bi gjohn
Big john
Bigj ohn
Bigjo hn
Bigjoh n
```